# include_libraries for a single target only

Tags: cmake

In project with many multiple targets, I wish to add include libraries for a certain target only. I don't want to slow down compilation by adding many include libraries to all projects, and I do want that if I did not specify a required library as a dependency to the executable, it will fail in compile time, and not only in link time.

Is there any way to do that in CMake? Something like `target_link_libraries`, but only for include directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would not bother with a potential increase in compilation time, because you added many include-directories. Of course, you should test if it really is an issue.

You may try to specify the [COMPILE_FLAGS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_sf%3aCOMPILE_FLAGS) property directly on the source files, but this is likely not cross-platform and needs to be done on each source-file.

Alternatively, consider splitting up your project in subdirectories and write a separate CMakeLists.txt for each subdir. In that case, the include_directories() call is limited to the scope of the current project (and its subprojects) and you would have more fine-grained control over each project.

There may be an issue with requiring failure at compilation time: E.g. when using static libraries A, depending on B, depending on C: When someones links an exe/dll to A, the libs B and C are needed, but this is not necessarily detectable at compile-time... and difficult to solve generically with CMake.

Comment: the compilation time is the smaller issue, the fail early is the big issue.

Comment: Then the next question is: are we dealing with multiple dependent static libraries? If so, it will be difficult, although with some create preprocessor, cmake hackery perhaps achievable